# RichTextBox last line save to string in wpf

Tags: wpf, string, save, richtextbox

Hy i need some advices to my problem ... 
I try to save last line from a richtextbox in a string to insert it in a db. 
I insert lines in textbox dinamicaly and i need last line all the time to be saved.
I  used `richtextbox.SelectAll`
I didnt get any results using `FlowDocument`.
Using `SelectALL` is not what i need.
I am sending a command through serial port to microcontroller and i am getting back a response in a terminal :

```
AddMessageToReceiveTerminal(string.Format("S-a transmis catre COM: {0}", tbSend.Text));
AddMessageToReceiveTerminal(string.Format("S-a receptionat de la COM: {0} ", temper));
```

the recieved string contains the temperature measurement from microcontroller. 
I need to save it from the terminal which is a richtextbox in a file or preferabli in my database.

Comment: Post code and clean up the question

Comment: Going to assume english is not your first language.   string[] words = text.Split('\n');

Comment: You assume correct :)) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this loop is not the most efficient but that is a copy paste from something similar

```
string lines = tbSend.Text;
string lastSting = String.Empty;
foreach (string line in lines.Split('\n'))
{
    lastString = line;
}
```